# Converting json to geoJSON on frontend

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, leaflet, geojson

I have a json object as such:

```
{
 "data_type" : "trainings"
 "description" : "Training in Narewa"
 "district" : "Rewa"
 "gps_lat" : "-18.1295977111"
 "gps_lon" : "178.556147326"
 "id" : 24
 "location" : "Tavuya"
 "program" : "Training in Nadi"
 "project" : "Entrepreneurship"
 "province" : "Rewa"
}
```

how can I turn this into a geojson object?
Please note this is example within an array 12 objects with these key value pairs so most likely I'm going to loop the solution through 12 times.
I'll need to use frontend javascript to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will most likely have to create a parser yourself. I think the best way to do this in the geojson format would be creating a **feature list**. I.E.

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -18.1295977111,
                    178.556147326
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "data_type" : "trainings",
                "description" : "Training in Narewa",
                "district" : "Rewa",
                "id" : 24
                "location" : "Tavuya",
                "program" : "Training in Nadi",
                "project" : "Entrepreneurship",
                "province" : "Rewa"
            }
      }, (add more for more entrys)

    ]
}
```

where properties acts as a way to store any custom data. So you could create a new json var doing

```js
var newDat = {};
```

and then use .push to append new items that are in the geojson format above. As far as my knowledge geojson acts just as normal json files it just has a specific structure. I hope this helps :).

Comment: Parsing this was the way to go yep thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

You need to create geojson object, and then push elements from your json as features to geojson. Here's the solution for your example.

```
var json = [
    {
     "data_type" : "trainings",
     "description" : "Training in Narewa",
     "district" : "Rewa",
     "gps_lat" : "-18.1295977111",
     "gps_lon" : "178.556147326",
     "id" : 24,
     "location" : "Tavuya",
     "program" : "Training in Nadi",
     "project" : "Entrepreneurship",
     "province" : "Rewa"
    },
    {
     "data_type" : "trainings",
     "description" : "Training in Narewa",
     "district" : "Rewa",
     "gps_lat" : "-18.1295977111",
     "gps_lon" : "178.556147326",
     "id" : 24,
     "location" : "Tavuya",
     "program" : "Training in Nadi",
     "project" : "Entrepreneurship",
     "province" : "Rewa"
    }
];
var geojson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": []
};
json.forEach(element =>{
    feature = {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                element.gps_lat,
                element.gps_lon
            ]
        },
        "properties": element
        }
    geojson.features.push(feature);
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).